# A question about digital sum of polynomials over $\mathbb Z^+$

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series

Given a polynomial with positive integer coefficients , let $a_n$ be the sum of the digits in the decimal representation of $f(n)$ , $n∈\mathbb Z^+$ , then is it true that there is a number which occurs infinitely often in the sequence $a_1 , a_2 , a_3 , $ ...  ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Consider $f(10^n)$ with $n$ big.