# show there is a number that occurs infinitely often in the digital representation of a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I would appreciate some help with the following problem:

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with integral coefficients (possibly negative).
> Let $a_n$ be the digital sum in the decimal representation of $p(n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
> Show that there is a number which occurs in the sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ infinitely often.

Note this problem is related to but distinct from the simpler problem here:
[A question about digital sum of polynomials over $\mathbb Z^+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384105/a-question-about-digital-sum-of-polynomials-over-mathbb-z).

Comment: Is the digital sum, the sum of digits or the repeated sum of digits till I get a single-digit number?

Comment: I've basically quoted everything the question says, which is itself a bit ambiguous. I'd assume it means the former option, i.e. just the sum of digits. This is also a bit weird in the case with negative integers but I assume in that case you just ignore the negative sign.

Comment: Just consider $P(10^n)$ for all $n \geqslant M$ where $M$ is sufficiently large. They will all have the same sum of digits.

Comment: This doesn't work in the case where the coefficients can be negative.
If $p(x)= -6x+4$ we get P(10^n) = -56, -596, -5996, ... which clearly have digital sums that increase by 9.

Comment: You will have to make a few modifications before that. Let $Q(x)=P(x)$ if the leading coefficient of $P$ is positive, and $Q(x)=-P(x)$ if the leading coefficient is negative. Then, define $R(x)=Q(T+x)$ where $T$ is sufficiently large, which will ensure that $R$ has positive integer coefficients only. Now, $R(10^n)$ will have same sum of digits for $n \geqslant M$, showing that $P(10^n+T)$ will have the same sum of digits.

Comment: @Haran I had the same idea almost at the same time :) This actually works. Formulate it as an answer , I will upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the polynomial $P(x)$. We first define:
$$Q(x)=
\begin{cases}
P(x) & \text{if the leading coefficient of $P$ is positive} \\
-P(x) & \text{if the leading coefficient of $P$ is negative}
\end{cases}$$
This ensures that $Q$ has positive leading coefficient. Now, define:
$$R(x)=Q(x+T)$$
where $T$ is a sufficiently large positive integer. We have:
$$Q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^d a_dx^d \quad (a_d>0)$$
$$Q(x+T)=\sum_{i=0}^d a_d(x+T)^d=a_dx^d+(dTa_{d}+a_{d-1})x^{d-1}+\cdots+(a_dT^d+\cdots+a_0)$$
Each coefficient of $R(x)$ is like a polynomial over $T$ with positive leading coefficient as $a_d>0$. Thus, the sufficiently large choice of $T$ ensures that $R$ has all positive integer coefficients.

Now, for sufficiently large choice of $M$, we have $R(10^n)$ has the same sum of digits for all $n \geqslant M$ as the decimal expansion of $R(10^n)$ is simply the coefficients of $R$ separated by a string of $0$s. We have:

$$P(10^n+T)=\pm Q(10^n+T) = \pm R(10^n) \quad (n \geqslant M)$$

Thus, $P(10^n+T)$ has the same sum of digits for all $n \geqslant M$ where $M,T$ are sufficiently large.

Comment: (+1) as promised